# Play with scoped G 41 in Red Orchestra 2

Tags: red-orchestra

I've reached level 50(the maximun) with G 41 and the max I got is the bayonet.

How can I play with scoped version of G 41 ? Did I have to reach the **Veterean** level of Elite Rifleman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found the answer. The **Veteran** grade on Elite Assault(the class that *Axis* haves the G 41) have nothing to do with it scoped version, indeed. The scoped version can be used when you reach the Veteran grade of the **Marksman** class:

```
    The "Marksman" class is issued the rifle fitted with a 
ZF41 1.5x long eye relief sight.
```

From [Tripwire Interactive Wiki](http://wiki.tripwireinteractive.com/index.php/G_41(W)).